# TabHost shows default Activity after showing new activity for a while

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost, tabactivity

Thanks for reading.

I am facing a problem where when I start a new `Activity` in my `TabHost`, the new `Activity` only shows up for a few seconds before returning to the default `Activity` in that `Tab`.

I am using the TabHost for laying out 5 tabs in my app. In one of the tabs, I start a new `Activity` as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
LocalActivityManager manager = MyActivityGroup.ActivityGroup.getLocalActivityManager();
MyActivityGroup.ActivityGroup.replaceView(manager.startActivity("NewActivity", intent).getDecorView() );
```

In this `NewActivity`s' `onCreate()`, I am calling a speech recognition libraries' `startRecord()` method which is implemented as follows:

```
private void startRecognition() {
        try {
             recognizer.startRecord(new SpeechRecognizerEvent() {
                 @Override
                 public void onRecognitionComplete(SpeechResult result) {
                           //get result data
                 }
}
```

All I know is there is a `SpeechFrameworkActivity` associated with this library in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

If I comment out calling the `startRecord()` method, the `NewActivity` does not disappear and continues to show.

I am just clueless about what is going wrong.

From the logs, all I see is this one line:

```
09-21 21:16:44.860: DEBUG/PhoneWindow(6737): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4794d9b8 has no id.
```

I tried using `onConfigurationChanged()` in my `MainTabActivity` but that didn't solve the problem.

Please help! Any help/pointers would be great appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may happen due to less memory 
in my case i clear the memory every time before using 
and it work may be in ur case it works 
or use system.gc
or clear buffer just try this if it helps u .